# How to determine the source of a request in a distributed service system?

Tags: web-services, search, server, neural-networks, grid-computing

Map/Reduce is a great concept for sorting large quantities of data at once. What to do if you have small parts of data and you need to reduce it all the time?

Simple example - choosing a service for request.

Imagine we have `10` services. Each provides services host with sets of request `headers` and post/get arguments. Each service declares it has `30` unique keys - `10` per set.

```
service A:
name
id
...
```

Now imagine we have a distributed services host. We have `200` machines with `10` services on each. Each service has `30` unique keys in there sets. but now to find to which service to map the incoming request we make our services post unique values that map to that sets. We can have up to or more than `10 000` such values sets on each machine per each service.

```
service A machine 1
name = Sam
id = 13245
...
service A machine 1
name = Ben
id = 33232
...
...
service A machine 100
name = Ron
id = 777888
...
```

So we get `200 * 10 * 30 * 30 * 10 000 == 18 000 000 000` and we get `500` requests per second on our gateway each containing `45` items `15` of which are just `noise`. And our task is to find a service for request (at least a machine it is running on).

On all machines all over cluster for same services we have same rules.

We can first select  to which service came our request via rules filter `10 * 30`. and we will have `200 * 30 * 10 000 == 60 000 000`.

So... `60` mil is definitely a problem... 
I hope to get on idea of mapping `30 * 10 000` onto some artificial neural network alike Perceptron that outputs `1` if `30` words (some hashes from words) from the request are correct or if less than Perceptron should return 0. And I’ll send each such Perceptron for each service from each machine to gateway. So I would have a map `Perceptron <-> machine` for each service.

Can any one tall me if my Perceptron idea is at least “sane”? Or normal people do it some other way? Or if there are better ANNs for such purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just tack a machine ID on top of the service identifier? That way you have 31 unique keys, which specify both the service and machine, and you're left with a lookup into 10000.

Also, I don't really understand your math. From what I see, it looks more like:

You're choosing from (200 machines) * (10 services per machine) * (10000 values per service).

If you filter by service based on the 30 keys then you're looking at (200 machines) * (1 service) * (10000 values per service).  Where does the extra 30 come from in there?